# R: how to zero-out a data.frame except a given column

Tags: r, dataframe

```
mydat <- head(iris)
> mydat
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

I want to zero-out all the columns except for `col = "Petal.Width"`. That is, I want the output to look like

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1            0           0            0         0.2       0
2            0           0            0         0.2       0
3            0           0            0         0.2       0
4            0           0            0         0.2       0
5            0           0            0         0.2       0
6            0           0            0         0.4       0
```

Is there a quick way to do this in R without writing a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `col` from `names` of `mydat` and replace all other values with 0.

```
col = "Petal.Width"
mydat[setdiff(names(mydat), col)] <- 0
mydat

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1            0           0            0         0.2       0
#2            0           0            0         0.2       0
#3            0           0            0         0.2       0
#4            0           0            0         0.2       0
#5            0           0            0         0.2       0
#6            0           0            0         0.4       0
```

In `dplyr` you can use `across` like :

```
library(dplyr)
mydat %>% mutate(across(-all_of(col), ~0))
```

Comment: Awesome. Is it possible to store this as `mydat2`? Or should I just make a copy of `mydat` first using `mydat2 <- mydat` and then do `mydat2 %>% mutate(across(-all_of(col), ~0))`

Comment: `mydat2  <- mydat %>% mutate(across(-all_of(col), ~0))` shoudl work.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 1:5
z <- 1:5
d <-data.frame(x,y,z)

d[,-2] <- 0 #zero out all columns but column 2
d
x y z
0 1 0
0 2 0
0 3 0
0 4 0
0 5 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too:

```
head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

iris[,-4] <- 0
 head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1            0           0            0         0.2       0
2            0           0            0         0.2       0
3            0           0            0         0.2       0
4            0           0            0         0.2       0
5            0           0            0         0.2       0
6            0           0            0         0.4       0
```